# Python algorithm to categorize meta patterns in data

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to perform a machine learning classification task.  I'd like to categorize the rows by identifying patterns in the missing data across the rows.  For example, in the data below, some clusters of rows have nan values for the 2nd and 3rd columns, while others have nan for the first and second.

```
[[1, 5, nan, nan, 0],
[2, -4, nan, nan, 6],
[2, 4, 7, 5, 2],
[nan, nan, 1, 6, 5],
[nan, nan, -2, 0, 1],
[0, 1, nan, nan, 8]]
```

The dataset I'm working with is about 400 columns and 600,000 rows.  There are patterns in the columns that contain nan values.  I'm trying to come up with a reasonably fast algorithm to identify the clusters of rows that have similar patterns of nan values.

My first thought was to use pandas.isna() to convert to binary and then try K-means clustering, but that was pretty slow for even 2000 rows.  I came across a few other algorithms, but they were all pretty slow, even with a fairly small sample size.

Any suggestions on an appropriate way to categorize these patterns?

Comment: Try Birch clustering, it's O(n) in nature

Comment: This may be silly approach, but running 0.4*600k matrix on pandas may be too much. Read it row by row and do filtering as text? At least that's the way I have to work with genome data files.